# boxcox transformation method compare.(R, python)

Tags: python, r

I have a simple question: I want to make a boxcox transformation on a series of data. I tried different method, then got different results. Why I don't have consistent result?

Data:(in R form)

```
x <- c(112,118,132,129,121,135,148,148,136,119,104,118,115,126,141,135,125,149,170,170,158,133,114,140,145,150,178,163,172,178,199,199,184,162,146,166,171,180,193,181,183,218,230,242,209,191,172,194,196,196,236,235,229,243,264,272,237,211,180,201,204,188,235,227,234,264,302,293,259,229,203,229,242,233,267,269,270,315,364,347,312,274,237,278,284,277,317,313,318,374,413,405,355,306,271,306,315,301,356,348,355,422,465,467,404,347,305,336,340,318,362,348,363,435,491,505,404,359,310,337,360,342,406,396,420,472,548,559,463,407,362,405,417,391,419,461,472,535,622,606,508,461,390,432)
```

Plan A: R script from boxcox definition

```
par2 <- 200
par3 <- 100
numlam <- par2 + par3 + 1
n <- length(x)
c <- array(NA,dim=c(numlam))
l <- array(NA,dim=c(numlam))
mx <- -1
mxli <- -999
for (i in 1:numlam)
{
  l[i] <- (i-200-1)/100
  if (l[i] != 0)
  {
    x1 <- (x^l[i] - 1) / l[i]
  } else {
    x1 <- log(x)
  }
  c[i] <- cor(qnorm(ppoints(x), mean=0, sd=1),sort(x1))
  if (mx < c[i])
  {
    mx <- c[i]
    mxli <- l[i]
    x1.best <- x1
  }
}
print(paste("best lambda:", mxli))
hist(x)
hist(x1.best)
```

Plan B: R package

```
library(MASS)
bc= boxcox(lm(x~x))
lmbd2 = bc$x[which(bc$y == max(bc$y))]
print(paste("best lambda:", lmbd2))
```

Plan C: python package

```
from scipy.stats import boxcox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [112,118,132,129,121,135,148,148,136,119,104,118,115,126,141,135,125,149,170,170,158,133,114,140,145,150,178,163,172,178,199,199,184,162,146,166,171,180,193,181,183,218,230,242,209,191,172,194,196,196,236,235,229,243,264,272,237,211,180,201,204,188,235,227,234,264,302,293,259,229,203,229,242,233,267,269,270,315,364,347,312,274,237,278,284,277,317,313,318,374,413,405,355,306,271,306,315,301,356,348,355,422,465,467,404,347,305,336,340,318,362,348,363,435,491,505,404,359,310,337,360,342,406,396,420,472,548,559,463,407,362,405,417,391,419,461,472,535,622,606,508,461,390,432]
plt.hist(x, bins=10)
y,lmda = boxcox(x)
print(lmda)
plt.hist(y, bins=13)
```

I got 3 different for lambda: 0.22, 0.1414, 0.1480

Comment: you can view the r code `MASS:::boxcox.default`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script optimizes correlation. Both `MASS::boxcox()` in R and
`scipy.stats.boxcox()` in Python use maximum likelihood estimation, instead.

The difference between R and Python comes from the fact that `MASS::boxcox()`
uses a fairly sparse grid search by default. By using
a finer grid, we can get the results to agree:

```r
> with(boxcox(x ~ 1, lambda = seq(0.1, 0.2, by = 0.001)), x[which.max(y)])
# [1] 0.148
```

With `scipy` you can also optimize correlation, to match your script’s result:

```py
>>> scipy.stats.boxcox_normmax(x, method='pearsonr')
# 0.21082925698127897
```

Further, in R, you can also manually optimize for the log-likelihood function ([following `scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox_llf.html#scipy.stats.boxcox_llf)):

```r
llf <- function(x, lambda) {
  y <- (x^lambda - 1) / lambda
  n <- length(x)
  (lambda - 1) * sum(log(x)) - n / 2 * log(sum((y - mean(y))^2) / n)
}

optimize(function(lambda) -llf(x, lambda), interval = c(-2, 2))
#> $minimum
#> [1] 0.1480227
#> 
#> $objective
#> [1] 679.5431
```